# Error while running npm run build command in react after installing sass

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass

I installed sass using the command `npm install --save-dev sass`, while running `npm run build` command I'm getting the following error

```
npm ERR! Failed at the react-app@1.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\md3\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-27T06_26_11_296Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass

Try this `npm install -g sass`